# Error: Can't create test file

Tags: mysql

I am trying to reset password of my root but it keeps giving this error.

And here is the statement that I use

```
bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="my.ini" --init-file="D:\\mysql-init.txt"
```

And here is the mysql-init.txt:

```
use mysql;
update mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE user= 'root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

It gives the error:

```
Can't create test file C:\....\data\Fatima.lower-test
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that permission was not granted to write to particular folder. 
I granted permission by :

```
right click folder
go to properties
go to security tab
grant permissions
```

Comment: This works. Weird thing is, my MySQL instance was running for a while since after the first install, after a reboot I had to do this